# Detect modifier key release in X11 root window

Tags: x11, hotkeys, xlib

The overall goal is like Windows' Alt-Tab, so I will use these keys for explanation. I want:
Press Alt -> press Tab -> [ popup appears ] -> press Tab any time holding Alt -> release Alt -> [ popup disappears ].

I can't detect final Alt release.

1. Trivial approach: grabbing Alt-Tab:

   ```
   XGrabKey (dpy, 
     XKeysymToKeycode(dpy,XK_Tab), Mod1Mask,
     root, True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
   ```

   (full code: http://pastebin.com/K2P65KJn)

   Result:

   [ Alt pressed ]
   [ Tab pressed ]
   Pressing Alt-Tab reported
   [ Tab released ]
   Releasing Alt-Tab reported
   [ Alt released ] -> nothing reported
2. Grabbing both Alt-Tab and Any-Alt:

   ```
   XGrabKey (dpy, 
     XKeysymToKeycode(dpy,XK_Tab), Mod1Mask,
     root, True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
   XGrabKey (dpy, 
     XKeysymToKeycode(dpy,XK_Alt_L), AnyModifier,
     root, True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
   ```

   (full code: http://pastebin.com/75mD1tjA)

   It works!

   [ Alt pressed ]
   Pressing Alt reported
   [ Tab pressed ]
   Pressing Alt-Tab reported
   [ Tab released ]
   Releasing Alt-Tab reported
   [ Alt released ]
   Releasing Alt-Alt reported

   But this hides any Alt combination from any running program.
   I can't find the way to push back events which don't belong to us (tried XSendEvent), and overally grabbing Alt from the start looks too invasive.
3. Grabbing Alt after first Alt-Tab press, then ungrab Alt after its release.

   Unfortunately, first Alt release is still not reported:

   [ Alt pressed ]
   [ Tab pressed ]
   Pressing Alt-Tab reported, Alt grabbed here
   [ Tab released ]
   Releasing Alt-Tab reported
   [ Alt released ] -> nothing reported! subsequent Alt press/release are reported, though not useful:
   [ Alt pressed ]
   Pressing Alt reported
   ...

Do I need to mess with low-level xinput or there is another way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Perhaps replaying the events with `XAllowEvents` works? If not, I think you might indeed have to go to Xinput2. You could also try asking this on the xorg mailing list since the X community on SO is rather sparse.

Comment: XGrabKey is rather greedy; have you tried handling the regular XKeyPress/ReleaseEvents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you won't get a `KeyRelease` event if you have registered interest in it after the key was pressed.

I can think of two different ways around this.

1. Select `KeyReleaseMask` for *all* windows (and keep track of appearing and disappearing windows); *or*
2. Once you know Alt is pressed, poll the keyboard state with `XQueryKeyboard` every 0.1 second or so until it's released.

I have tested the first method and it seems to be working:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>            
#include <X11/Xutil.h>           
#include <stdbool.h>             
#include <stdio.h>               

void dowin (Display* dpy, Window win, int reg)
{                                             
  Window root, parent;                        
  Window* children;                           
  int nchildren, i;                           

  XSelectInput (dpy, win, reg ? KeyReleaseMask|SubstructureNotifyMask : 0);
  XQueryTree (dpy, win, &root, &parent, &children, &nchildren);            

  for (i = 0; i < nchildren; ++i)
  {                              
    dowin (dpy, children[i], reg);
  }                               

  XFree(children);
}                 


int main()        
{                 
    Display*    dpy     = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window      win     = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
    XEvent      ev;

    unsigned int    alt_modmask       = Mod1Mask;
    unsigned int    ignored_modmask   = 0; // stub
    KeyCode         tab_keycode       = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy,XK_Tab);
    KeyCode         alt_keycode       = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy,XK_Alt_L);

    dowin (dpy, win, True);

    XGrabKey (dpy,
            tab_keycode,
            alt_modmask | ignored_modmask,
            win,
            True,
            GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);


    while(true)
    {
        ev.xkey.keycode = 0;
        ev.xkey.state = 0;
        ev.xkey.type = 0;

        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        switch(ev.type)
        {
            case KeyPress:
                printf ("Press %x: d-%d\n", ev.xkey.window, ev.xkey.state, ev.xkey.keycode);
                break;

            case KeyRelease:
                printf ("Release %x: %d-%d\n", ev.xkey.window, ev.xkey.state, ev.xkey.keycode);
                break;

            case MapNotify:
                printf ("Mapped %x\n", ev.xmap.window);
                dowin (dpy, ev.xmap.window, True);
                break;

            case UnmapNotify:
                printf ("Unmapped %x\n", ev.xunmap.window);
                dowin (dpy, ev.xunmap.window, False);
                break;

            default:
                printf ("Event type %d\n", ev.type);
                break;
        }

    }

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!
The only bug so far is "BadWindow" X error when unmap event triggers XSelectInput for non-existing window (because it's closed or WM workspace changed). To prevent termination on these errors, I just ignore them: http://pastebin.com/Q2UVJa61 . I'm afraid this introduces some race conditions or memory leaks under asynchronous X execution, so I'll still be grateful for any review.

Comment: It's a harmless race condition (tje server sends you unmapnotify, then kills the window faster than you can process it). It's oerfectly normal, just ignore this condition.