# How do you read KeyPress and ButtonPress events on the root window in X11/Xlib?

Tags: c, x11, xlib, xserver

I am writing a C program that draws to the root window. (This part works)

I now need to accept keyboard and mouse input on the root window (clicking and keypresses on the root window). I tried this:

```
XSelectInput(display, rootWindow, KeyPressMask);
XNextEvent(display, &event)
```

but a KeyPress never comes. I also tried using `ButtonPressMask` but this creates an error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess
```

Is it possible to do this without having to hook into all input? I have seen this idea on stack overflow: [Detect modifier key release in X11 root window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087079/detect-modifier-key-release-in-x11-root-window) but it hooks into all input as far as I can tell.

I am using i3wm, so I have nothing as my default root window. (incase this helps)